# Every item identified grouped by 3 and every second set of 3

Tags: c#, math

Apologies for the Title, I wasn't sure how to really explain, but it will be clearer with the description.

I had a requirement to render a set of div's in an HTML page from a single data source, in my case it's a ASP.net repeater with an ItemTemplate, the div would have to have a "first", "second", "third" class at every 3 items, and at every 2nd set of three would have a class "reverse" added from a single 0 based index, so as an example:

```
first 
second 
third 
first reverse
second reverse
third reverse
first 
second 
third 
first reverse
second reverse
third reverse
first 
second 
third
```

I managed to do it with this (simulating the repeater):

```
    int i = 0;
    string[] row = new string[]{"first", "second", "third"};
    while(i<50){
        Console.WriteLine(row[i % 3] + " " + (((i-(i % 3)+1)%2) == 0 ? "reverse" :""));
        i++;
    }
```

(or, https://dotnetfiddle.net/vRA3Lr)

For each "first", "second" and "third" it was obvious I had to use the Mod operand, but for the "reverse" group, I was stuck.

I wasn't really sure how to start my goggling to find some solutions, so decided to give it a go by trial and error, and managed to come up with `((i-(i % 3)+1)%2)` but I am not sure why it's working! I know, embarrassing, but I'm really curious to find out:

- How does it work? Not looking for a scientific explanation, more like why am I getting 0 from that formula at every second group of three?
- Is it the best solution for the requirements above?

Thanks,
P.

Comment: This pattern is basically a group with 2 subgroups of 3 elements. So, you could take modulo 6 and check if remainder < 3 to find the element's group and then append reverse accordingly

Comment: Bingo, so (i % 6 > 2 ? "reverse" :"") thanks, much simpler and quicker solution that makes sense :D